# Google material design guideline for openlayers3 map controls

Tags: material-design, maps

Knowing that the guidelines say that you must not overuse the fab component, but I am struggling to create an alternative for these controls. Do you guys have any suggestions how this can be done better?

[image]

**Update:**
After playing around I got to this:

[image]

Tnx for the suggestions.

Comment: Check google maps and that's it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to put them all in a single bar, like this one.

[image]

A fab component is for the primary action related to your screen. None of these actions seem to be "primary".

You could also separate the **+** and **-** buttons from the 2 others, and keep the **i** and the ruler as fab.

Comment: tnx going to give that a shot!